# Where can I find a list of sphenic numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number),

> A Sphenic number is a positive integer which >is the product of three distinct prime
>   numbers.

Anybody knows whether there is a list, say first 1000 sphenic numbers? It would be much helpful to know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the title question.  (The answer to your previous question is, quite clearly, "infinitely many.")

Comment: Does it mean that the set of sphenic numbers is infinite? Since, prime numbers are infinite it is understandable. But, I hear the further go to the positive X-axis the fewer you get primes. So, the set of shpenic numbers at hand might be finite?

Comment: To get a sphenic number, you just take any three distinct primes (and there are clearly infinitely many ways of choosing three primes!) and multiply them.

Comment: Thanks. But, isn't it just n*(n-1)*(n-2), where n is the number of distinct primes?

Comment: @Sazzad, you should really explain the term "sphenic" (or any other uncommon term you are using) before using it :-)

Comment: It would be n(n-1)(n-2)/6 if there were a finite number of primes, as order doesn't matter

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Ok, thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first 10000 are listed [here](http://oeis.org/A007304/b007304.txt). (Found via [Wikipedia: Sphenic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A007304).)